# $Q$ factor refers to what on a lowpass filter? (EE kind of definition)

Tags: lowpass-filter, bandwidth, resonance

For what I'm learning, the bandwidth (of a BPF, for example) refers to the $\Delta$ between $f_L$ and $f_H$ at (usually) $-3\textrm{ db}$ from the $f_0$ (from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_(signal_processing)#/media/File:Bandwidth_2.svg)). For a peaking filter instead, $f_L$ and $f_H$ are situated (usually) at the peak $\textrm{dB Gain}/2$.

[Q Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor#/media/File:Bandwidth.svg) become $f_0 /\Delta$. It's clear till here.

- Now, if I take a lowpass filter, how is calculated $Q$ Factor?
- I have $f_0$, but how would I calculate the $\Delta$ of a lowpass?

There is no a "peak" as reference, so $-3\textrm{ dB}$ (or $\textrm{dB Gain/2}$) make no sense as references points for the "created" bandwidth.

Comment: Can you please clarify if you are referring to [low pass filters with resonance](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/svf/Bode_Plots_Second_Order_Lowpass.html)?. In that case, perhaps the points you are looking for are apparent from its frequency response (?)

Comment: actually paizza, the definition of Q for the peaking filter is more of a cookbook thing than it is "usually".  [we had a discussion about this not too long ago](http://www.aes.org/events/141/workshops/?ID=5197).

Comment: Not sure if its really only a "cookbook" thing :) From [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_(signal_processing)) : _The threshold value is often defined relative to the maximum value, and is most commonly the 3dB-point, that is the point where the spectral density is half its maximum value (or the spectral amplitude, in V or V/Hz, is more than 70.7% of its maximum)._  It also seems that "your" `dbGain/2` band edges (for the `Peaking` filter) refers to [Half power point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_power_point) (which is again -3db to the peak). It looks like all is related.

Comment: Here (more or less) I'm asking if a Low Pass Filter's band edge are situated at -3db as for a Band Pass Filter (for the standard convention). I see this "-3db" only when talking about band pass (or notch)...

Answer (score 3):

For basic lowpass and highpass filters, Q (quality) factor is not well defined.

Q factor is a useful metric for second-order **bandpass** frequency selective filters, as it shows their selectivity power. It can be defined as the ratio of the center frequency of passband to the bandwidth of passband, assuming that the system has only a single passband (which is indeed the case for a second-order system)

For a highpass filter, the passband width is infinite, hence this Q will be zero. And for a lowpass filter, Q will be 1/2 always. As a result, Q factor, as defined above, is not a useful merit for HighPass or Lowpass filters.

Note that there's also an identical **ringing** definition of Q, which focuses on the **resonation** power of those systems. Both are equally valid definitions but from different application perspectives.

Comment: So you are saying that for low (and high) pass, Q become "resonance"?

Comment: @paizza yes, kind of. **Q** is for *Q*uality (of resonance)! From [wikipedia's *Q factor* article's headline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor): *Q factor is a dimensionless parameter that describes how under-damped an oscillator or resonator is, and characterizes a resonator's bandwidth relative to its center frequency.*

Comment: Yes, but "and characterizes a resonator's bandwidth relative". Since I don't specify a bandwidth for a Low Pass filter, it refers to what? i.e. Q (resonance) of 2.4 of a Low Pass filter at 1khz refers to the bandwidth created by the resonance of the filter itself around that cutoff?

Comment: No, I refer to a LP filter using Q. If I use Q for a Peaking filter, it makes sense (its fc / delta, with a well-know delta). On a LP filter, Q is the same fc / delta (I guess, refering to resonance of the filter), but I don't understand to which delta its refering (the same -3db from the peaking f0 point? I don't think so...).

Comment: I try to reformulate: once I apply a Q Factor to a Low Pass filter (i.e. Q=2.4 and fC 1000hz), the bandwidth of the resonance introduced by the filter is relative to freq fL and fH of which peak? :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48879/discussion-between-paizza-and-fat32).

Comment: Oh ok, so also on Low/High Pass filter the bandwidth across the resonance refers to -3db to the peak (a peak that increase when resonance increase).

Comment: The [explanation](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/221887/does-q-factor-matter-for-low-pass-and-high-pass-filters) from EE.SE regarding Q-factor for low pass and high pass filters..

Comment: I trust you, but where is this convention written for Low Pass filters? For example, for Peaking filter, thats dbGain/2, not -3db. Thats why I reported EE, cant find anything about this :( Neither on wiki...

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess @robert bristow-johnson knows it... lets hope.

Comment: god, he will kill me :D I stressed him a lot days ago...

Answer (score 3):

[image]

So I once chaired a [workshop about Q](https://www.aes.org/events/141/workshops/?ID=5197) and I really wish we would nail down the definition for purposes of automation and consistent user experience.

So the transfer function is:

$$ H(s) = \frac{1}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_0}\right)^2+\frac{1}{Q}\frac{s}{\omega_0}+1} $$

Where $\omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{L C}}$ and $Q=\frac{\omega_0 L}{R}$ .

That's the EE definition for a LPF.

Now, if you look at the impulse response shown above, and to define $RT60$ as the time for this output to decay to -60 dB, then you get

$$ \frac{\omega_0}{2Q}  = \frac{2 \pi f_0}{2Q} = \ln(10)\frac{\frac{60}{20}}{RT60} $$

or

$$ Q = \frac{RT60}{2.1988} f_0 $$.

What this means is that for every unit of $Q$, the impulse response rings for 2.1988 cycles before it decays below -60 dB.  It appears that this is an approximation since the actual frequency of the ringing is a little different than $f_0$.  I forgot my thinking about this.

[image]

In case anyone is interested, it appears that I turned [slides into a pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z2sYy0DJLtvH9VTnbvGnKnx9kBbBH1HE/view).

Comment: So as you show the Q for the inductor is energy stored over energy dissipated which I believe is the EE definition of Q. Capacitors also have Q using the same relationship ($X_C/R$) but typically it is so much higher than that for the inductors that it can in most cases be ignored.

Comment: @DanBoschen I'm just showing idealized components.  For a parallel RLC filter it's the same because it's $$ Q = \frac{\omega_0 C}{1/R} = \frac{\omega_0 L}{R}$$  I think that's correct.  Lemme look at this.

Comment: I dunno why, but I am seeing mistakes in the equations I put up on slides.  Any continuous-time impulse response (of a system that has the same species of output as is input) needs to be in dimension of $\frac{1}{\mathrm{time}}$ and these $h(t)$ appear dimensionless.  I need to go over this and do something about it.

Comment: I would think h(t) should be dimensionless when it is translating the input to the output in the same units (such as volts to volts). Also a LPF (to be applicable to this  question specifically) would be series L shunt C  (with possible R in series with the L and possible R in parallel with C).

Comment: No, Dan.  Any $h(t)$ for any continuous-time LTI that is voltage-in-voltage-out has dimension of $\frac{1}{\mathrm{time}}$.  Look at the convolution integral and you should be able to see that right away.  But I also fucked up with the exponent in the second $h(t)$ in the slide at top.  This is embarrassing.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: I wanna make clear that this is fucked up.  I'm pretty sure that the "$f_0$" in the exponent in the second $h(t)$ in the top slide does not belong there.  I gotta deal with this, but there's fresh snow out there now, and I'm going skiing.  Will fix this later.